# Parent blocking chain of queries

Tags: sql-server

--This query below is not executing. Please can someone assist to find out why?

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT session_id, blocking_session_id
FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_REQUESTS
WHERE session_id > 49 and blocking_session_id <> 0
 
UNION ALL
 
SELECT X.blocking_session_id AS session_id, ISNULL(Y.blocking_session_id, 0) AS blocking_session_id
FROM CTE X
OUTER APPLY [fn_get_blocking_session](X.blocking_session_id) Y
WHERE X.blocking_session_id <> 0
)
 
SELECT DISTINCT sdes.session_id, host_name, program_name, sqltext.TEXT, dmv.wait_type, dmv.wait_resource
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN SYS.dm_exec_sessions sdes ON c.session_id = sdes.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests dmv ON c.session_id = dmv.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dmv.sql_handle) AS sqltext
WHERE c.blocking_session_id = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

What does "*not executing*" mean?

Do you mean you're not getting any rows back? This is likely because you're filtering on `blocking_session_id <> 0` inside both parts of your recursive CTE, but then try to filter on the opposite `WHERE c.blocking_session_id = 0` when you `SELECT` against that CTE.

Also, why not just use Adam Machanic's [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) to find blocked and blocking queries?